# Call a function that calls an API multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to replicate a scenario where a web page contains multiple areas, each being updated by an API call and refreshed every X seconds.

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  console.log("interval start");
  getData;
  console.log("interval end");
}, 5000);

//for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
//    console.log(i);
//    setTimeout(getData, 5000);
//}

function getData(url, id) {
  console.log("getData start");
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    console.log('data=' + data);
    $(id).html(data);
  });
};

getData('@Url.Action("GetTemperature", "SomeData")', '#temp');
getData('@Url.Action("GetStockPrice", "SomeData")', '#stock');
getData('@Url.Action("GetStateName", "SomeData")', '#state');
getData('@Url.Action("GetARandomDate", "SomeData")', '#myDate');
```

Here are the logs:

> - getData start
> - AjaxTimer:95 getData start
> - AjaxTimer:95 getData start
> - AjaxTimer:95 getData start
> - AjaxTimer:98 data=188
> - AjaxTimer:98 data=Vermont
> - AjaxTimer:98 data=88
> - AjaxTimer:98 data=2014-08-26T00:00:00
> - AjaxTimer:83 interval start
> - AjaxTimer:85 interval end
> - AjaxTimer:83 interval start
> - AjaxTimer:85 interval end
> - AjaxTimer:83 interval start
> - AjaxTimer:85 interval end

`getData` is not called a second time. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: `getData` as a statement by itself does nothing; it's just a reference to the function. You need to actually call the function with some arguments to execute it, as you are in the last 4 lines of your logic. *However*, making 4 AJAX requests every 5 seconds is not a good pattern to be following. It will not scale well and is in effect DDOS'ing your own server. A better idea would be to firstly return all data from a single endpoint, and also to use Websockets/Server Sent Events to retrieve it.

Comment: Yes, `getData` is not being called, but changing it to `getData()` will call it

Comment: Rory, thank you for the input - makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setInterval` is this:

```
    window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log("interval start"); // Log to console
        getData;                       // A variable
        console.log("interval end");   // Log to console
    }, 5000);
```

All function calls in JavaScript must end with `()`, so just update the middle line to

```
        getData();
```

and getData will be called by the interval.

Comment: It'll be called, but with no arguments.

Comment: Sure, but that's near to the original source. Adding arguments is possible, of course.